# View Yii2 theme without database?

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I'm the frontend developer (strictly frontend) for a Yii2 project, and I've never worked with Yii2 before. I was sent the repo of the whole Yii2 site - front & backend, but my colleagues forgot to send me a database dump to work with.

But going through the `views` folder, I see what looks like everything required for a PHP site. Can I just set up a webserver and view / modify these locally without requiring the entire rest of the system including database?

Not really my area of expertise here, any advice is appreciated.

Comment: You need to setup project along with database. You cannot simply run html files and see the output on screen

Comment: how can work you application without a proper data  (database table)   access?  if you app can work without access to datatable you can run you app  ..I think it's very unlikely that your application will work without access to data

Comment: I should have clarified - the app functionality (the actual Yii2 part) I don't have to use right now, my job is only in the PHP site design of things. I don't know if Yii will allow me to do what I'm trying to

Comment: "but my colleagues forgot to send me a database dump to work with", you don't always need the dump file. Try to look at folder `/console/migrations/` and see if there is any migration files there. Then try to `migrate` using this method http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-migrations.html